# TypeError: FunctionSuppliedToMap takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Tags: python, dictionary

```
def MapperGender():
    if gender=='Male':
        return 0 
    else:
        return 1

data['GenderMapped']=list(map(MapperGender,data['Sex']))
```

getting error:

```
TypeError 
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-99063d9bb2fe> in <module>
----> 1 data['GenderMapped']=list(map(MapperGender,data['Sex']))

TypeError: MapperGender() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

Comment: Check out the title, clarified.. it’s not “any” function or even the “map” function.. it’s a specific function used in a specific way, as clarified in the error message. I simply put in a more generic placeholder for the function name, saying the usage.

Answer (score 1):

You need an argument for your function

```
def MapperGender(gender):
    if gender=='Male':
        return 0 
    else:
        return 1

data={"Sex":["Male","Female"]}
data['GenderMapped']=list(map(MapperGender,data['Sex']))
print(data) 
# Output : {'GenderMapped': [0, 1], 'Sex': ['Male', 'Female']}
```